# Sharepoint RunWithElevatedPrivileges vs Impersonation

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, impersonation

I spent hours on a strange "bug" concerning a web method from a .NET web service requesting AD information user rights.

The good news is I  fixed the bug but I would understand why the correction is effective.

**The web method with the bug is the following:**

```
public bool ValidateTask(string originatingUser)
{
    SPUserToken userToken = null;

    // get the System account for impersonation
    string userToken = site.SystemAccount.UserToken; 
    using (SPSite rootSite = new SPSite(site.ID, userToken)) 
    {
        using (SPWeb web = rootSite.OpenWeb()) 
        {
            // get the domain name of the application pool of the web app
            string servicesDomain = 
                StringUtilities.GetDomain(site.WebApplication.ApplicationPool.ManagedAccount.Username);
            // get the domain name of the user
            string accountsDomain = StringUtilities.GetDomain(originatingUser);

            PrincipalContext ServicesDomainContext = 
                new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, servicesDomain);
            PrincipalContext AccountsDomainContext = 
                new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, accountsDomain);

            // COMException when the FindByIdentity is called because 
            // AccountsDomainContext.connectedServer throw exception
            using (UserPrincipal usr = 
                UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(AccountsDomainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, originatingUser))
            {
            // get user groups memberships
            }
        }
        // check groups memberships and return the true or false
    }
}
```

**The web method with the correction is the following:**

```
public bool ValidateTask(string originatingUser)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
        delegate ()
        {
            ...
            using (SPSite rootSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = rootSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    // get the domain name of the application pool of the web app
                    string servicesDomain = 
                        StringUtilities.GetDomain(site.WebApplication.ApplicationPool.ManagedAccount.Username);
                    // get the domain name of the user
                    string accountsDomain = StringUtilities.GetDomain(originatingUser);

                    PrincipalContext ServicesDomainContext = 
                        new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, servicesDomain);
                    PrincipalContext AccountsDomainContext = 
                        new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, accountsDomain);

                    using (UserPrincipal usr = 
                        UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(AccountsDomainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, originatingUser))
                    {
                    // get user groups memberships
                    }
                }
            }

           // check groups memberships and return the true or false
        }
    ); // end of delegate method
}
```

===========================================================================

In sharepoint, I thought Impersonation and RunWithElevatedPrivilege would produce the same result. 
So My questions ares:

1- So why the RunWithElevatedPrivilege works ?

2- What is the credential when we elevates privilege in the WebMethod context ? This is the identity pool account of SharePoint Web Services Root ?

3- I could we trace the credential of the  2 methods ?

Answer (score 1):

The RunWithElevatedPrivileges runs the code inside in a new thread. This new thread runs under the account of the current application pool. If you call it e.g. under http://localhost/_vti_bin/yourservice the application pool is the application of the web application on port 80.
The usage of new SPSite with user token opens only the SPSite in the context of the defined user and does not start new thread. 
You can track the current user by calling WindowsIdentity.Current

Comment: Thx for the reply. 
My asmx file resides in template\layouts folder and the dll is in the GAC.
The user token is the "sharepoint\system" account. But when we impersonate with the new SPSite(siteId, usertoken), we have full rights in sharepoint context but when we execute queries on AD (or file system) the WindowsIdentity is still the current user calling the web service.
That's why the RunWithElevatedPrivileges is more powerfull due to the new Thread with the ApplicationPoolidentity.